# Python 3: Plot GPS position on maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, gps

I have a table in my SQL data base on my server where are save in real time some GPS positions. 
I would like to make a script in Python for plot and display the position in real time on OpenStreetMap or equivalent.

If it far easier, I could also download a map picture and an plot the position on the maps.

If you can give me the headlines for my project it's will be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/index.html). The library allows you to create really cool interactive maps, however I am not sure if it has real-time features. Nonetheless, nothing stops you from creating a script and re-running it every minute or so to refresh the positions on the plot.